# Python freezing on unexpected CL output with subprocess module

Tags: xml, python-3.x, version, subprocess, bzip2

I am writing a script to get version numbers from command line programs by using their appropriate 'version' command line flag i.e. --version, -v etc. The program as a whole uses a regex to get just the actual version number from the text output and then compares it to various conditions of minimum required or maximum allowed version pulled from an xml conf file etc.

The script works perfectly until executing bzip2.

For most programs there is no issue with the following code:

```
args = 'cmd --version'

output = subprocess.getstatusoutput(args)
```

pretty cut and dry. However! If you try this with, say, bzip2 (and so far this is the only program I've had an issue with) ala 'bzip2 --version' python "freezes" and you must ctrl-C to break out with no output recorded of course.

I've tried various variations such as going the long route i.e.:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT

proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
while(True):
    code = proc.poll()
    if(code is not None):
        break
    line = proc.stdout.readline() # or even read()
    etc.
```

Regardless of which method I use to extract the relevant text, Python always hangs after a certain point. I've tried .kill() at certain points to head off the locking event but to no avail.

It's just with bzip2 I think because for some reason it's still expecting input with the --version flag.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @Foon - I have Python versions 2.7.1 and 3.2 installed (fresh fc15 install). My version of bzip2 is 1.0.6. I tried your code verbatim with both Python 2 and 3 and I get the same result as before; blank line, no prompt, must ctrl-C out. I wonder if it's bzip2 version 1.0.6?

Comment: @lennart-regebro - I'm starting to think it's my version of bzip2 (1.0.6)--I tried your code and I get the same issue as before. If I type commands while at the blank prompt, nothing happens no matter what I type. To clarify, I can get bzip2 to spit out its --version information, it just doesn't go back to prompt, or in the case of my code, stuff it into a variable.

Comment: I also wanted to add that after running 'bzip2 --version' manually from a prompt, it prints two extra lines after the version text that lead me to believe something else squirrly is going on:

`bzip2: I won't write compressed data to a terminal
bzip2: For help, type 'bzip2 --help'.`

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT,PIPE

proc = subprocess.Popen(("bunzip2","--version"),stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT)
data = proc.stdout.read()
print data
```

now works with bzip2 1.0.6 (or bunzip2 1.0.6 but they're the same application).
That really looks like a bug in bzip2 to me... --version should print version and quit, not try to read/write to stdin.

Comment: Hmm.  I just tried running this on an FC14 box (which has bzip2 1.0.6) and am seeing the same behavior you're seeing.  So, you're not going insane or else we both are.

Comment: Updated code above slightly... specifically, bunzip2 still adds the complaining lines but gives you the version information without hanging

Comment: Also... if you hit control-D with the hanging version, it will print out the bzip2 magic and quit

Answer (score 0):

My bzip2 is not expecting input even with --version, and you can test that easily for yourself by just running the  command.

This code works for me on Python 2.4-3.2:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT

import sys
proc = subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1:], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline() # or even read()
    while True:
        line = proc.stdout.readline() # or even read()
        if not line:
            break
        print(line)
    code = proc.poll()
    if(code is not None):
        break
```

No hanging of any kind. I can even run `vi foo.py` with it. Obviously that doesn't work very well as vi suddenly doesn't have a terminal to talk to, but I get no hanging. Doing `:q!` will quite vi as usual. So if your bzip2 expects input, just input something and it will continue. If this works, then that is the problem.